# R : Calculate frequency of a transaction and increment for every transaction

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, frequency, counting

I have a dataframe called cust

```
    > head(cust,15)
    Txn_date  Cust_no   Credit
1  2013-12-02 12345000  400.00
2  2013-12-02 12345000  300.00
3  2013-12-02 12345000  304.71
4  2013-12-02 12345000  475.00
5  2013-12-02 12345000  325.00
6  2013-12-02 34567890  1390.00
7  2013-12-02 34567890  100.00
8  2013-12-02 34567890  500.00
9  2013-12-02 23232323  5.00
10 2013-12-02 23232323  130.00
11 2013-12-02 23232323  5975.00
12 2013-12-02 23232323  3711.00
13 2013-12-02 14345422  12530.50
14 2013-12-02 14345422  3312.00
15 2013-12-02 98765432  370.00
```

To calculate total amount, based on the Cust_no, I have used the `within` and then applied `cumsum` to it, like below

```
newCust <-within(cust, {
   RunningTotal <- ave(cust$Credit, cust$Cust_no, FUN = cumsum)})
```

and hence my result is this, as you can see the Credit is getting incremented based on the cust number

```
>head(newCust,15)
   Txn_date  Cust_no   Credit   RunningTotal    
1  2013-12-02 12345000  400.00   400.00
2  2013-12-02 12345000  300.00   700.00
3  2013-12-02 12345000  304.71   1004.71
4  2013-12-02 12345000  475.00   1479.71
5  2013-12-02 12345000  325.00   1804.71
6  2013-12-02 34567890  1390.00  1390.00
7  2013-12-02 34567890  100.00   1490.00
8  2013-12-02 34567890  500.00   1990.00
9  2013-12-02 23232323  5.00     5.00
10 2013-12-02 23232323  130.00   135.00
11 2013-12-02 23232323  5975.00  6110.00
12 2013-12-02 23232323  3711.00  9821.00
13 2013-12-02 14345422  12530.50 12530.50
14 2013-12-02 14345422  3312.00  15842.5
15 2013-12-02 98765432  370.00   370
```

Now my question is, how do I find out the number of transactions for every Cust_no, using the above logic of `within` and `length`?? or maybe, some other logic.

I am not getting the **desired output** as shown below even I tried using `aggregate()` and `apply`..

```
   Txn_date  Cust_no   Credit   Frequency   
1  2013-12-02 12345000  400.00   1
2  2013-12-02 12345000  300.00   2
3  2013-12-02 12345000  304.71   3
4  2013-12-02 12345000  475.00   4
5  2013-12-02 12345000  325.00   5
6  2013-12-02 34567890  1390.00  1
7  2013-12-02 34567890  100.00   2
8  2013-12-02 34567890  500.00   3
9  2013-12-02 23232323  5.00     1
10 2013-12-02 23232323  130.00   2
11 2013-12-02 23232323  5975.00  3
12 2013-12-02 23232323  3711.00  4
13 2013-12-02 14345422  12530.50 1
14 2013-12-02 14345422  3312.00  2
15 2013-12-02 98765432  370.00   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
 within(cust, Frequency <- ave(seq_along(Cust_no), Cust_no, FUN=seq_along))
 #     Txn_date  Cust_no   Credit Frequency
 #1  2013-12-02 12345000   400.00         1
 #2  2013-12-02 12345000   300.00         2
 #3  2013-12-02 12345000   304.71         3
 #4  2013-12-02 12345000   475.00         4
 #5  2013-12-02 12345000   325.00         5
 #6  2013-12-02 34567890  1390.00         1
 #7  2013-12-02 34567890   100.00         2
 #8  2013-12-02 34567890   500.00         3
 #9  2013-12-02 23232323     5.00         1
 #10 2013-12-02 23232323   130.00         2
 #11 2013-12-02 23232323  5975.00         3
 #12 2013-12-02 23232323  3711.00         4
 #13 2013-12-02 14345422 12530.50         1
 #14 2013-12-02 14345422  3312.00         2
 #15 2013-12-02 98765432   370.00         1
```

Or using `splitstackshape`

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 getanID(cust, 'Cust_no')
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(cust)[, Frequency:=1:.N, by=Cust_no]
```

Comment: 1++ for `seq_along`. How did I miss that!! Thanks much @akrun. and yes, I shall look into the `splitstackshape` package.

Comment: @sunitprasad1  Thanks.  `splitstackshape` has some convenient functions for `reshaping` datasets